# TkinterでWM_DELETE_WINDOWを設定したら起動したと同時にクローズドウィンドウが実行されてしまいます。

Tags: python, tkinter, マルチスレッド

10×20の盤を設定してその中をセルがw,d,s,aキー操作で移動できるプログラムを作ろうと思い、以下のコードを作成したところ、1回実行するときは想像通りに動くのですがウインドウを消して、もう一回実行しようとするとキー操作に反応しなくなり「RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop」とエラーが出てしまいました。(IDEを再起動するとまた1回だけ正常に動きます。)
[image: 表示されるGUI]

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

class client_gui:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = []

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title(u'canvas')
        root.geometry('200x400')
        root.configure(background='blue')
        
        #cell面の構築
        for i in range(20):
            tmp = []
            for j in range(10):
                tmp.append(tk.Canvas(root, width = 20, height = 20, bg='red', highlightthickness=0))
                tmp[j].create_rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20, fill = 'white', tag="cell")
                tmp[j].grid(row=i, column=j, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)  
            self.cells.append(tmp)
        
        #セル色の変更
        self.x=4
        self.y=5
        self.cells[self.x][self.y].itemconfig("cell", fill="black")
        
        keyboard.on_press_key("w", lambda _:self.move(-1, 0))
        keyboard.on_press_key("d", lambda _:self.move(0, 1))
        keyboard.on_press_key("s", lambda _:self.move(1, 0))
        keyboard.on_press_key("a", lambda _:self.move(0, -1))
        
        
        root.mainloop()
        
            

    def move(self, dirc_x, dirc_y):
        print(str(dirc_x))
        self.cells[self.x][self.y].itemconfig("cell", fill="white")
        self.x+=dirc_x
        self.y+=dirc_y
        self.cells[self.x][self.y].itemconfig("cell", fill="black")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client_gui()
```

そこで、ウィンドウクローズイベントが別のスレッドで動いており、ウィンドウを消してもそのスレッドが終了していないことが原因であるのではと考え、client_guiクラスを以下のように書き換えたところ、プログラムを実行したと同時(ウィンドウの×ボタンを押していなくても)にウィンドウクローズを確認する小画面が出てきてしまいました。

```
class client_gui:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = []

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title(u'canvas')
        root.geometry('200x400')
        root.configure(background='blue')
        
        #cell面の構築
        for i in range(20):
            tmp = []
            for j in range(10):
                tmp.append(tk.Canvas(root, width = 20, height = 20, bg='red', highlightthickness=0))
                tmp[j].create_rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20, fill = 'white', tag="cell")
                tmp[j].grid(row=i, column=j, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)  
            self.cells.append(tmp)
        
        #セル色の変更
        self.x=4
        self.y=5
        self.cells[self.x][self.y].itemconfig("cell", fill="black")
        #cells[2][5].itemconfig("cell", fill="black")
        
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing(root))
        
        keyboard.on_press_key("r", lambda _:print("r"))
        
        keyboard.on_press_key("w", lambda _:self.move(-1, 0))
        keyboard.on_press_key("d", lambda _:self.move(0, 1))
        keyboard.on_press_key("s", lambda _:self.move(1, 0))
        keyboard.on_press_key("a", lambda _:self.move(0, -1))
        
        
        root.mainloop()
        
        
    def on_closing(self, root):
        if tk.messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            root.destroy()
            

    def move(self, dirc_x, dirc_y):
        print(str(dirc_x))
        self.cells[self.x][self.y].itemconfig("cell", fill="white")
        self.x+=dirc_x
        self.y+=dirc_y
        self.cells[self.x][self.y].itemconfig("cell", fill="black")
```

WM_DELETE_WINDOWプロトコルはウィンドウクローズボタンが押されたときに実行される処理を紐づけられるという認識で合っているのでしょうか？　また、どのようにしたら正常にプログラムが動くのでしょうか？

Comment: `self.on_closing(root)` と記述すると関数(`self.on_closing`)が実行されてしまいます。`root.protocol()` の第2引数には関数インスタンスを指定する必要がありますので、`lambda` 関数を使って `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: self.on_closing(root))` とします。

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)かもしれませんね。最初の問題はIDEから実行(/デバッグ?)しているから発生しているのかもしれません。Windows10のPython 3.9.5では、最初のスクリプトをファイル(例えばboard.py)に作成して`python board.py`として実行した場合は、起動/終了を繰り返しても問題無く動作しています。